# useState initialState not being set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate):

> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as
>   the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

But I have the following component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const {position, setPosition} = useState(0);
  return `POSITION: ${position}`;
}
```

The component renders:

> POSITION: undefined

What am I missing?

Comment: const [position, setPosition]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState` returns an array. Look at its signature:

```js
function useState<S>(...): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>]
```

So you should write:

```js
const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid mistake.